# OR/And condition in spring dashboard filter

Tags: spring-boot, dashboard, spring-tool-suite

Is it possible to write the expression in boot dashboard filter with AND/OR condition?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not yet possible. Please raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues.

The design guideline behind this search box was to keep it as simple as possible and have just a simple "filter" text that gets matched against project names, working sets, and tags. If you file an enhancement request, it would be great if you could explain the setting and context a bit, provide a few examples why the AND/OR syntax would be useful or necessary, and how you would use that. We would like to understand the context a bit more before deciding on a final user experience for it.

Thanks!!!